# Where is id: { type: 'ID' } generated in in the featherjs models created by feathers-plus cli defined in the official jsonschema?

Tags: jsonschema, feathersjs

I have looked at the json schema docs and examples and do not see a type of ID as created in the json models by the generator. Example feathers-plus cli jsonschema

```
  properties: {
    // !code: schema_properties
    id: { type: 'ID' },
    email: {},
```

In the jsonschema official docs example id is defined like

```
"properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": ["string", "integer"],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed by JSON Schema.

According to the docs at https://github.com/feathers-plus/generator-feathers-plus/tree/master/docs/json-schema

> Feathers Models are based on JSON-schema.

This reads to me that their models are not quite JSON Schema.

If you want to know why, you should probably raise an issue on their github repo.